# A variant of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It seems that, if $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k=a$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$ converges for $|x|<1$ by the Cauchy–Hadamard theorem.

Can I show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,n} x^k$ converges for $|x|<1$ if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{k,n}=a_k$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k=a$?

Specifically, I'd like to argue:

that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,n} x^k$ converges to a postive constant for $0<x<1$, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{k,n}=a_k>0$ for all $k$;

that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,n} x^k$ converges to zero for $|x|<1$, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{k,n}=a_k=0$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample: Let $a_{k,n}=2^k$ for $k\le n$, and let $a_{k,n}=1$ for $k\gt n$.  For the second problem, use $0$ instead of $1$.

For worse behaviour, use $k!$ instead of $2^k$.